# UITableViewCell incorrect dynamic height calculation with SwiftUI view inside on iOS 15

Tags: uitableview, swiftui, ios15

I am trying to use SwiftUI view inside UITableViewCell that is working fine until iOS 15. On iOS 15 when I scroll table view and once initial visible cells go off screen and new cells being reused those are having extra height added.

[image]

Following is the source code.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView?.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView?.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView?.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView?.separatorColor = .white
        tableView?.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        20
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
        stack.axis = .vertical
        return stack
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupView()
    }
    
    func setupView() {
        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: TestView())
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(hosting.view)
        hosting.view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

}

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.green)
            .frame(height: 100)
    }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: When you mix UIKit and SwiftUI almost always it is your responsibility for sizing & alignments. It is not a bug.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi but this thing was working totally fine till iOS 14.x I think something has been changed in iOS 15 onwards.

Comment: As usual... something always changes when new version of Apple's OS comes. :)

Comment: Where you able to find a workaround for this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @tomidelucca Did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue as well.

Comment: @michaelthedeveloper There's something broken with the safe area inset. The hosting controller tries to apply the inset to the hosted view and that's the extra space shown. I ended up following this post https://defagos.github.io/swiftui_collection_part3/#fixing-cell-frames and creating a custom `UIHostingController` that uses reflection to ignore the insets.